# How to move the view when the keyboard presents with one textview but not another one

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, uitextview

I have a UITextView at the top, a UITextView in the centre and a UITextView at the bottom.
I want to move the view up when the keyboard presents if using the bottom UITextView or the centre UITextView but when using the top UITextView the view shouldn't move.

How do I make this work?

```
func showLoginKeyBoard()
{
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
}
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification)
{
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
    {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0
        {
            self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
        }
    }
}


func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView)
{
    if textView == centreTextView
    {
        showLoginKeyBoard()
    }

    if textView == bottomTextView
    {
        showLoginKeyBoard()
    }
}
```

Currently when any of the UITextViews becomeFirstResponder the view moves up which means when using the top UITextView it isn't visible.

How can I make sure the top UITextView doesn't move the view up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before answer your question ,
According to your code every time user click on textView you add Observer.Don't do this. Add observers at viewDidLoad() and don’t  forget to remove observers in viewDidDisappear(). Otherwise it will  cause to memory leaks.

Now,Answer to question

define fileprivate optional textView

```
var currentTextView:UITextView?
```

Then assign textField in **textViewDidBeginEditing**

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView){
   currentTextView = textView
}
```

now you can show or not according to currentTextView

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification){
     if let txtView = currentTextView{
         txtView != topTextView {
         //move up the view
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: I'm still trying to change all my code around for this to work because I had showLoginKeyboard() and keyboardWillShow together in a UIViewController extension as there are 3 controllers with this setup and the top and bottom controllers are custom class.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using IQKeyboardManager library which handles all your keyboard events with only a single line of code